# Warning: a promise was rejected with a non-error: [object Object]

Tags: promise, bluebird

I am gettings this warning from `bluebird`:

```
(node:29879) Warning: a promise was rejected with a non-error: [object Object]
```

and cant find any information/stack trace where its coming from, already looked through every `reject` and `throw`.

Does anyone has any hints how to find it? Is there any log option to get more infos or a stack trace?

thx

Comment: Have you enabled long stack traces?

Comment: Yes: `longStackTraces: true`; this works for all other caught errors.

Answer (score -1):

`Promise(function(resolve, reject) {
    reject(new Error(message));
})`

we can use  `reject(new Error(message))` instead of `reject(message)`, because the type of parameter of `reject()` should be `Error`, I resolved the warning in this way.